# Is There any Compatibility issue with prime faces (v .3.4) data table on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

Recently i have upgraded my IE 7 to IE 8 ever since that i'm having issue with data table,there is one page which contain few one type menus and below data table which shows records based on search criteria.whenever i go to that page whole page hangs in IE8 and not even able to move my mouse,i didn't have any issue in IE 7.is there any way to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with selectable datatables in IE8 for primefaces 3.4 that causes extreme performance degradation. You can read more about it in this thread: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24605

There's also an issue at http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4628 but it has not been accepted yet. You should star it to improve the chances of getting it fixed.

If you need to work around it right now you need to downgrade to primefaces 3.3 or use another browser.

Comment: Thanks @MatsT,i don't have any problem with other browsers,even i tried to degrade to 3.3.1 still the same situation. unfortunately IE is the customer preference for browser :(,

Comment: Yes, this seems to be specific to IE8. I haven't tried 3.3.1 as I went straight from 3.3 to 3.4, but I didn't have the problem in 3.3 and downgrading to that version fixes it.